How do I call a rest client from an interceptor?
If the client is not reactive, it returns null. When I make it reactive I notice that it enters the filter, returns to the endpoint and then returns to the filter. What I wanted is for it to resolve the verification of the token and put the user in a security context.
or any recommendations to do it another way? What I wanted to do is intercept the headers that came with a token and verify it against an external service
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@PreMatching
public class BearerTokenInterceptor implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(BearerTokenInterceptor.class);

    @Inject
    TokenizerService tokenizerService;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // Obtener el encabezado Authorization
        String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        // Verificar si el encabezado Authorization existe y tiene un token Bearer
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer".length()).trim();

            // Realizar la verificación de token de manera reactiva
            tokenizerService.verifyTokenService(token)
                    .onItem().transform(tokenizerResponse -> {
                        if (tokenizerResponse.getError() != null) {
                            LOG.info("Error de token: " + tokenizerResponse);
                            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
                        } else {
                            LOG.info("token correcto : " + tokenizerResponse);
                            HashSet<String> roles = new HashSet<>();
                            roles.add("admin");
                            for (Profile profile : tokenizerResponse.getPayload().getProfiles()) {
                                roles.add(profile.getName());
                            }
                            UserLogin user = new UserLogin(tokenizerResponse.getPayload().getFirst_name(), roles);
                            LOG.info("Usuario: " + user);
                            // Asignar el contexto de seguridad
                            requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
                               ...
                            });
                        }
                        return tokenizerResponse;
                    })
                    .subscribe().with(result -> {
                    }, failure -> {
                        LOG.error("Error al verificar el token: ", failure);
                        requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build());
                    });

        } else {
            LOG.info("No se encontró un token Bearer en la solicitud.");
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        }
    }
}


What does "If the client is not reactive, it returns null. When I make it reactive
"  mean exactly?
